read_excel in R failing to load derived values sometimes
I have an odd problem that's hard to reproduce. I'm reading in some excel files in R using the readxl. Sometimes, it fails to show some values that are derived from other sheets. The first sheet, which contains summary information and metadata, looks like this.

Where both the date and # of quadrats are values taken from another sheet.In that second sheet, the values that are read from are themselves derived from other cells in that same sheet. I know. I'm trying to build a database of some very old valuable data here so having to pull things in from someone else's excel files. Here's what that second sheet looks like. Note, the first instance of both the date and # of quadrats are themselves pulled from where they were manually entered elsewhere in the same sheet.

So, here's the thing. When I load the first sheet from this file
library(readxl)

a <- read_excel("orig.xlsx")

note that the # of quadrats and date are now filled with NAs or are just gone. actually, so is the site - SHIHC - which is itself derived from another sheet.
# A tibble: 175 × 32
   `SITE/DATE...1`  ...2   ...3 ...4  ...5  ...6   ...7 ...8 
   <chr>            <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1 # of QUADRATS    NA       NA chan… each  time…    NA NA   
 2 QUADRAT          SQ        1 2     3     4         5 6    
 3 SLIDE # (A,B)    NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA NA  

This bedeviled me, and I tried any number of things to make it work. The closest was specifying a different na argument, which made some of the values come back as 0, but not all of them.
So, to make a reprex, I tried to cut off the top few lines of each sheet and make it into its own file. Saved it. AND IT WORKED NORMALLY.
e <- read_excel("test_sebens.xlsx")
e

# A tibble: 3 × 26
  `SITE/DATE...1` ...2  SHIHC `33358` ...5  ...6   ...7  ...8
  <chr>           <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 # of QUADRATS   NA        4 changes each  time…    NA    NA
2 QUADRAT         SQ        1 2       3     4         5     6
3 SLIDE # (A,B)   NA       NA NA      NA    NA       NA    NA

Yeah, the date is weird, but it's just a number of days - very fixable with a script. Out of curiosity, I just resaved the original file into a new file, and it worked again!
b <- read_excel("Copy.xlsx")
b

# A tibble: 175 × 32
   `SITE/DATE...1`      ...2  SHIHC `33358` ...5  ...6   ...7
   <chr>                <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 # of QUADRATS        NA        4 changes each  time…    NA
 2 QUADRAT              SQ        1 2       3     4         5
 3 SLIDE # (A,B)        NA        0 0       0     0         0

Now, I'm working off of a mac. This was done on a PC (I think). But still, just re-saving the file suddenly making this work...... a) it makes me suspicious and b) I cannot scale this solution, as there are ~9K files I'm trying to merge here.
So, what is going on, and is there a scripted way I can fix it so the read in works? Thanks in advance.
Note, I also tried
library(openxlsx)

# Load workbook and read sheet
wb <- loadWorkbook("orig.xlsx")
dat <- read.xlsx(wb, sheet = 1)

which just produced NA values and

# different lib
library(tidyxl)
library(unpivotr)

# Extract raw data from the Excel file
xlsx_data <- xlsx_cells("orig.xlsx")

which crashed my R session.

Possibly relevant: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/618

But perhaps an excel macro would be able to batch open and resave the excel files?

Have you tried reading Excel but using one of the other R<-> Excel packages?
